# Lazy load Vue components once, retain data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i'm lazy loading some components, but these components do AJAX requests. I want the component's to retain their data if they are hidden again, as to not do multiple AJAX requests.

This is my `main` component which contains both lazy loaded components:

```js
<template>
    <div class="media-component">

        <vehicle-image-slider :vehicle-id="vehicleId"
                              v-if="active === 'vehicle-image-slider'"
                              key="vehicle-image-slider"></vehicle-image-slider>
        <vehicle-360-viewer :vehicle-id="vehicleId"
                            v-if="active === 'vehicle-360-viewer'"
                            key="vehicle-360-viewer"></vehicle-360-viewer>

        <a href="javascript:void(0)" @click="active = 'vehicle-image-slider'">Slider</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" @click="active = 'vehicle-360-viewer'">360</a>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
const Vehicle360viewer = () => import('./Vehicle360Viewer.vue');
const VehicleImageSlider = () => import('./VehicleImageSlider.vue');
export default {
    data: function() {
        return {
            active: 'vehicle-image-slider'
        }
    },
    components: {
        'vehicle-360-viewer': Vehicle360viewer,
        'vehicle-image-slider': VehicleImageSlider
    },
    props: [ 'vehicleId' ]
}
</script>
```

I'd imagine `v-if` is the wrong thing to use on the components, however I don't want to load the component unless it is displayed.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#keep-alive

Comment: keep-alive as just suggested or workaround with css property to hide the component without destroying it

Comment: @Dmitry thanks, didn't know about that one!